# What is the best way to compare two arrays and flag the updated value?

Tags: jquery, arrays, compare, key-value

Currently I have serialized an array (`initial_form_array`) of a form that gets defined on load of the page.  After changing a form field I create a new serialized array (`updated_form_array`) of the form.  Before progressing to the next step of the form I  parse through the initial array and compare it to the form array after a change to pinpoint which value has changed.  To do this, I am using `$.inArray` in the following manner:

```
if(initial_form_array != updated_form_array){
  
   $.each( updated_form_array, function( key, value ) {

       var name  = value['name'],
             value = value['value'];

       var comparison_value = $.inArray( value,  initial_form_array );
       if( comparison_value == -1 ) {
           console.log( "found an edit" );
    }
  }
}
```

So in the above example you can see that when the statement `found an edit` gets logged to the console it is because the value does not exist in the initial form array.  The issue is that this is just checking for whether or not the value is in the initial array.  So, if the value has changed from `123` to just `23` it would not make it to the  `found an edit` location since `23` is within `123`.

With this being the case, is there a better way to do this?  If this is a fine way to do it, is there a way to further clarify that the comparison is for an exact match rather than just determining if the value match is in the array?

Comment: `$.inArray` should not be returning true for a partial match. Have any examples?

Comment: If initial form array is objects that are same structure `{name:'foo', value:123}` this matching approach won't work though. Would be comparing a primitive value to the whole object with `$.inArray`

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can not compare two arrays doing `if(arr1 === arr2)`. That only checks if they are the exact same array object and doesn't check what's in the arrays.

Following should give you something to work with

```js
// iniital on page load
const initial_form_array = getArr();
// create a map object for easy loop using name as key
const init_map = new Map(initial_form_array.map(o=>[o.name,o.value]))

// change some values for demo and log differences
doFormChanges();
logDiff();

// log manual changes
$('#myForm').submit(e => {
  e.preventDefault();  
  logDiff();
})


function logDiff(){
    console.clear()
    const update_arr = getArr();
    const diff = update_arr.filter(o => init_map.get(o.name) !== o.value)
                            .map(o => ({...o, prev_val: init_map.get(o.name)}));
    if(!diff.length){
       console.log('No changes')
    }else{
       console.log('Diff from original:',diff);
    }
}


function getArr() {
  return $('#myForm').serializeArray();
}

function doFormChanges() {
  $('[name="age"]').val(30);
  $('[name="message"]').val('Yahoo');
}
```

```css
form div {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div><button>Test Me</button></div>
  <div><input name="fname" value="Foo"></div>
  <div><input name="lname" value="Bar"></div>
  <div><input name="age" value="37"></div>
  <div>
    <select name="location">
      <option value=""> Pick one</option>
      <option value="Australia" selected="">Australia</option>
      <option value="India">India</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div><textarea name="message">Blah blah blah</textarea></div>


</form>
```